# is there a way to make your website look the same on all screen sizes..... my site looks horrible on mobile but different on desktop

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I designed a UI for a website  and when the team did it. the desktop version looks okay but  when they opened the site on a different screen(mobile) its totally messed. misarranged  texts don't fit where they're supposed to.

I used Figma as my design tool. Is there any way to correct that in figma or with the coding to make the site look the same on all screens?

I only designed the UI for the desktop screen thinking it could work for all screens

i don't know how to go about converting the desktop design back into mobile. i'm a beginner

Answer (score -1):

It's common for websites to require different designs for desktop and mobile screens, as the screen sizes and user interactions vary significantly between these two platforms. Designing for mobile responsiveness is crucial to ensure your website looks and functions well on a variety of devices.

Here's what you can do to address this issue and make your design mobile-friendly:

**1- Responsive Design in Figma:**

Open your Figma project with the desktop design.
Create a new frame or duplicate your existing one to represent a mobile screen (common sizes are 320px or 375px width for phones).
Adjust the layout, text sizes, and elements to fit the smaller screen. You may need to stack elements vertically, reduce text sizes, and simplify the design for mobile.
Figma has features for setting constraints on elements to make them adapt to different screen sizes. Use these to ensure elements resize and reposition properly when switching from desktop to mobile views.

**Media Queries in CSS:**

When you or your development team code the website, use CSS media queries to apply different styles for different screen sizes. This is the standard way to make a website responsive.
For example, you can define styles specific to screens of certain widths and adjust the layout accordingly. Here's an example of a media queries in CSS:

**@media (max-width: 1399.9px)** {

/* CSS styles for screens with a maximum width of 991.9px (commonly used for Desktop) */

}
**@media (max-width: 1199.9px)** {

/* CSS styles for screens with a maximum width of 1199.9px (commonly used for Desktop) */

}
**@media (max-width: 991.9px)** {

/* CSS styles for screens with a maximum width of 991.9px (commonly used for tablets) */

}
**@media (max-width: 767.9px)** {

/* CSS styles for screens with a maximum width of 767.9px (commonly used for tablets and smaller desktops) */

}
**@media (max-width: 575.9px)** {

/* CSS styles for screens with a maximum width of 767.9px (commonly used for smaller desktops) */

}

You can adjust you design layout according to all devices using above media queries.